# Using full Dart SDK with Flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

Is there any way to tell Flutter use more newer dart sdk version? I found it a bit tricky, because it checks some hashes in flutter/bin/cache/*.stamp. And when I'm trying to make a symbolic link to homebrew installed dart sdk it cannot build flutter_tool. To do that I've removed flutter_tool.stamp and flutter_tool.snapshot files. Something else needed?

I'm not actually sure if it is a need or not, but these tools are still in beta, for me it sounds logic to use edge versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flutter ships with a customized Dart SDK (for example with the web parts stripped).
The Flutter SDK is tightly bound to a specific Dart SDK version and there is no reliable way to make Flutter work with any other Dart SDK than the one it is installed with.

Comment: Things like [this](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/14991) are making development with Flutter nearly impossible, wanted to try to fix it with upgrading used Dart SDK version.

Comment: Doesn't look like many are affected. I didn't follow closely and I don't get how that would be different with a different Dart SDK version.